# Corollary to the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem

Tags: inequality, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and let $Y\subseteq X$.

> If $\sup_{y\in Y}\left|f\left(y\right)\right|<\infty$ for every $f\in X^*$, then $\sup_{y\in Y}\left\|y\right\|<\infty$.

Could someone please provide a hint? I feel like this should be super straightforward.

Comment: This is exactly one of the big theorems about Banach spaces. Look in that chapter...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I read the chapter on Banach spaces and couldn't make a connection. Moreover, this statement doesn't assume $X$ is Banach.

Comment: What you ask is just a special case of the "Uniform Boundedness Principle", also known as the "Banach-Steinhaus Theorem".

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, it feels like I need to show that $X$ and $X^*$ are isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: No, you just need to know that $||x||$ is the same as its norm as a linear functional on $X^*$. That is, $||x||=\sup_{||f||\le1}|f(x)|$. (Follows from Hahn-Banach.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, I convinced myself that that is the case. However, I do not see how to use that in tandem with the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to prove my assertion. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $y\in Y$, consider the function $\hat y\in X^{**}$ given by $$\hat y(f)=f(y).$$
Your hypothesis is that 
$$
\sup\{|\hat y(f)|:\ y\in Y\}<\infty. 
$$
By the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle), 
$$
\sup\{\|\hat y\|: \ y\in Y\}<\infty. 
$$
The last ingredient is the equality $\|\hat y\|=\|y\|$. 
This follows directly from the well-known equality 
$$
\|y\|=\sup\{|f(y)|:\ f\in X^*,\ \|f\|=1\}. 
$$